# After installing Ubuntu my headphones don't work. What's the problem?

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 in my laptop. In Ubuntu I can hear music fromm my headphones and my speakers without any problem. But I noticed that after I installed Ubuntu in my laptop the headphones did not work on Windows 7.
After trying lots of things such us updating my sound drivers I reboot my laptop with the hadphones connected to it. It worked!
But it only works that way, so I wonder if someone could help me solving this problem. I know that the problem is from Windosws and not Ubuntu, but It started after installing Ubuntu OS on my laptop so I came here because I can't found any solution on the internet.
Thank you all.

Comment: It **sounds** ( :) ) like an issue with your Windows system. I would say it is a coincidence that happened at the same time your Ubuntu install. Your Ubuntu install uses a different partition and drivers/settings. When you boot/start into Windows or Ubuntu you are practically using a different machine; same hardware but still totally different. I would check the Windows forums.

Comment: Thanks @elemer82 I visited some Windows forums too, but i did not find anything. I hope that you'll be luckier than me in terms of having an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is because on start up we detect the audio device as being your head phones otherwise we use the speakers.

You can change the default play back device similar to how windows does it.

Just go to settings and look for sound settings, or just click the volume tray icon and click settings that way.  After that select the correct device.  [image]

Comment: The problem is not with Ubuntu (directly) @Goddard

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Yes I have just tried it @Goddard

Comment: Sometimes in my case I have multiple head phone devices and I also even need to restart the application so it uses the correct output device.  This happens a lot when using adobe flash to me any way.

Comment: I'm not talking about restarting an app. Is about restarting my laptop. And on Ubuntu I don't have any problem, only on Windows @Goddard

Comment: Oh I see.  That is impossible.  Ubuntu being installed has no effect on your Windows install.